# Visual Studio Team Services workspace error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I created a Visual Studio 2013 MVC project in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate using Visual Studio Team Services through [visualstudio.com](http://visualstudio.com). I have since reinstalled Windows and Visual Studio 2013 and have reopened the solution and receive error:

> The solution you have loaded is bound to the source control server at https://{myaccount}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection, but no workspace on that server could be located. If you do have a workspace on this server, and you want this solution to be opened under source control,
>   connect to that server using Team Explorer and then re-open the solution.

I am having difficulty locating how to setup and manage workspaces on my local machine and Team Services.

Comment: Did you do the thing the error message says to do?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open visual studio and connect to your team project you should then be able to open the solution explorer. Once open you should see your project grated or as It is not maped locally.

Right click on your desired mapping folder level and map it to your local disk.

Note: You will need to map it to another location and pull across any uncommitted changes.